# Design pattern: aggregate state for parent from child states in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child, state-machine

I have a Meeting model, which has many Participants. Each participant can take several actions against a Meeting (enroll, accept, decline etc.). Meeting status (pending, confirmed etc.) depends on latest action of each participant and its own attributes (expired date etc.)

For example, if all participant accept, then meeting status will be "confirmed". However, if after meeting is confirmed, one participant proposes a new time (because of a time conflict), then meeting now becomes "pending".

How should I model state in Meeting? Should I serialize (i.e., create a latest_state column in events table) current state? If so, how can I use state machine which based on child objects' actions?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Meeting status depends on only the most recent action of each one of the participants? What does 'action' include?

Comment: For example, if all participant accepts, then meeting status will be confirmed. However, if after being confirmed, one participant propose a new time (because of a time conflict), then meeting is now pending. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution would be to trigger a meeting status update when the Participant model is updated:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting
  after_update :update_meeting_after_change

  def update_meeting_after_change
    self.meeting.update_status if self.status_changed?
  end
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants

  def update_status
    #logic here
  end
end
```

`self.status_changed?` will return `true` if the `Participant`'s `status` attribute changed during the update